# Unknown identifier within template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm wondering why I a compile error in the following:

```
#include <unordered_map>

    template <typename T_Key, typename T_Value>
    class Iterator
    {public:
        //std::unordered_map<T_Key, T_Value>::iterator iter;  // GIVES ERROR syntax error: identifier 'iterator'
        std::unordered_map<int, int>::iterator iter; // WORKS
        
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
typename std::unordered_map<T_Key, T_Value>::iterator iter;
```

`iterator` is what's known as a *dependent name*, because it's meaning cannot be known without knowing what `T_Key` and `T_Value` are. Therefore the compiler needs a hint as to what kind of entity it is. Syntactically it could be a type name or it could be a static class member. `typename` tells the compiler that it's a type.

I believe C++ rules have changed or are changing on this subject, and `typename` is required less frequently than before. In contexts where the name can only reasonably be a type, `typename` will no longer be necessary. Maybe someone else can provide the full details.

Comment: Doh!!! Again, I've had this problem so many times. I'm on Visual Studio, I believe other compilers give more helpful errors.